# First row is selected by default upon form loading

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void FormatdgvParts(DataGridView d)
    {
        d.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        d.MultiSelect = false;
        d.ReadOnly = true;
        d.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        d.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    private void FormatdgvProds(DataGridView d)
    {
        d.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        d.MultiSelect = false;
        d.ReadOnly = true;
        d.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        d.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    private void Display()
    {
        dgvParts.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvParts.DataSource = Inventory.AllParts;
        dgvProds.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvProds.DataSource = Inventory.Products;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormatdgvParts(dgvParts);
        FormatdgvProds(dgvProds);
        Display();
    }
```

Any ideas on how to not get the first row selected when it loads?

I've tried d.CurrentRow.Selected = false; - threw an exception

d.Rows[0].Selected = false; - threw same exception

Comment: `[DataGridView].CurrentCell = null;`

Comment: Tried adding it to FormatdgvParts and Display function and still same problem.

Comment: Because you're calling those methods from the Constructor. Try from the `OnLoad()` override (or `Load` event) -- Or, you could write, e.g., `_ = Handle; _ = dgvParts.Handle; dgvParts.CurrentCell = null;`

Comment: Thank you! That worked.

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   [datagridview].CurrentCell.Selected = false;
}

That's all it took for those google searching

Comment: Note that you can also call `[DataGridView].ClearSelection();`. This has a slightly different visual effect than setting `.CurrentCell = null` (though it causes the same call), maybe you like it better. In any case, you have to call any of these when the Controls' Handles have already been created.

Comment: The .CurrentCell = null; seems to have fixed the issue. I'm at the point now to where if it works, then I'm going to roll with it and I'll work on cleaning up my code at a later date. I really do appreciate your help though!